# WebSQL query optimization help - CASE WHEN makes query 400 ms slow

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

Can somebody tell me why 'CASE WHEN' makes it so slow and how to optimize / fix it, please ?

It is needed to get the items that are pinned to be put first in the result and in order.

I could probably do it after the sql query but i think it would be faster, when done right, if this sorting is done inside the sql query.

slow query ~490ms

```
SELECT 
    places.id AS place_id,
    url,
    title,
    thumbnails.score AS score,
    thumbnails.clipping AS clipping,
    thumbnails.lastModified AS lastModified,
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pinned pi WHERE pi.place_id = places.id) AS pinned
FROM places
    LEFT JOIN thumbnails ON (thumbnails.place_id = places.id)
    LEFT JOIN pinned j ON (j.place_id = places.id) WHERE (hidden == 0)
ORDER BY case when j.id is null then 1 else 0 end,
    j.id,
    frecency DESC LIMIT 24
```

Removing the 'CASE WHEN' part:
query ~6ms

```
SELECT
    places.id AS place_id,
    url,
    title,
    thumbnails.score AS score,
    thumbnails.clipping AS clipping,
    thumbnails.lastModified AS lastModified,
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pinned pi WHERE pi.place_id = places.id) AS pinned
FROM places
    LEFT JOIN thumbnails ON (thumbnails.place_id = places.id) WHERE (hidden == 0)
ORDER BY frecency DESC LIMIT 24
```

Table info:

```
var Create_Table_Places =
    'CREATE TABLE places (' +
        'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,' +
        'url LONGVARCHAR,' +
        'title LONGVARCHAR,' +
        'visit_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0,' +
        'hidden INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,' +
        'typed INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,' +
        'frecency INTEGER DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL,' +
        'last_visit_date INTEGER,' +
        'dateAdded INTEGER,' +
        'lastModified INTEGER' +
    ')';

var Create_Table_Thumbnails =
    'CREATE TABLE thumbnails (' +
        'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,' +
        'place_id INTEGER UNIQUE,' +
        'data LONGVARCHAR,' +
        'score REAL,' +
        'clipping INTEGER,' +
        'dateAdded INTEGER,' +
        'lastModified INTEGER' +
    ')';

var Create_Table_Pinned =
    'CREATE TABLE pinned (' +
        'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,' +
        'place_id INTEGER UNIQUE,' +
        'position INTEGER,' +
        'dateAdded INTEGER,' +
        'lastModified INTEGER' +
    ')';
```

Comment: Sql optimizer can be a fickle mistress. I suggest reading this article and then revisiting your query and see if any insights strike you. http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether there are fundamental differences in the execution of queries, use [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html).
In SQLite 3.7.almost15, your queries have the following plans:

```
selectid order from detail
-------- ----- ---- ------
0        0     0    SCAN TABLE places (~100000 rows)
0        1     1    SEARCH TABLE thumbnails USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_thumbnails_1 (place_id=?) (~1 rows)
0        2     2    SEARCH TABLE pinned AS j USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_pinned_1 (place_id=?) (~1 rows)
0        0     0    EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1        0     0    SEARCH TABLE pinned AS pi USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_pinned_1 (place_id=?) (~1 rows)
0        0     0    USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY

selectid order from detail
-------- ----- ---- ------
0        0     0    SCAN TABLE places (~100000 rows)
0        1     1    SEARCH TABLE thumbnails USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_thumbnails_1 (place_id=?) (~1 rows)
0        0     0    EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1        0     0    SEARCH TABLE pinned AS pi USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_pinned_1 (place_id=?) (~1 rows)
0        0     0    USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

These two plans are almost identical, except for the duplicate `pinned` lookup.
If your SQLite doesn't execute the queries this way, update it.

In you first query, you can remove the subquery for the `pinned` field because you are already joining with the `pinned` table, and you're executing exactly the same lookup that was done for the join; use `j.id IS NOT NULL` instead.

Your `CASE WHEN` has the purpose of sorting the `NULL`s after the other values.
You can get the same effect by [converting all `NULL`s](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) to some value that is [sorted after numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparisons), such as a string:

```
... ORDER BY IFNULL(j.id, ''), frecency DESC
```

However, in theory, this should not have much of a runtime difference from `CASE WHEN`.